# fuseki Error - File Initialization Exception

Tags: java, bigdata, jena, fuseki

I'm running jena-fuseki server on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to load the dataset as below:

```
./fuseki-server --loc="/home/dataset.json.bz2" /ds
```

The error that keeps popping is as under:

```
[2018-05-21 23:37:07] Server     INFO  Running in read-only mode for /ds
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Server     INFO  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.7.0
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/home/apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/home/apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0/run
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///home/apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0/run/shiro.ini
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Config     INFO  Template file: templates/config-tdb-dir
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Config     INFO  TDB dataset: directory=/home/dataset.json.bz2
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: caught: Existing file: /home/dataset.json.bz2
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@74cf8b28{/,file:///home/apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.AssemblerException: caught: 
Existing file: /home/dataset.json.bz2
doing:
root: file:///ds#tdb_dataset_readwrite with type: 
http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#DatasetTDB assembler class: class org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.DatasetAssemblerTDB

at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:165)
at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:144)
at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:93)
at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.getDataset(FusekiBuilder.java:120)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataServiceCustom(FusekiBuilder.java:73)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataAccessPoint(FusekiBuilder.java:65)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.configFromTemplate(FusekiSystem.java:324)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initServerConfiguration(FusekiSystem.java:248)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiSystem.java:207)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.serverInitialization(FusekiServerListener.java:96)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:137)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.runFuseki(FusekiCmd.java:367)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:351)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:103)
at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:67)
Caused by: org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: Existing file: /home/aman/Downloads/latest-all.json.bz2
at org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location.ensure(Location.java:162)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location.<init>(Location.java:98)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location.create(Location.java:66)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.DatasetAssemblerTDB.make(DatasetAssemblerTDB.java:56)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.DatasetAssemblerTDB.createDataset(DatasetAssemblerTDB.java:48)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:157)
... 41 more
[2018-05-21 23:37:08] Server     INFO  Started 2018/05/21 23:37:08 IST on port 3030
```

The size of the dataset I'm trying to load is around 120 GB. I also tried loading by extracting the dataset and loading json format. Also, I tried to load the .nt(N triplet) format of the dataset. But the same error occured. The localhost:3030 says 
    HTTP ERROR 503 Problem accessing /. Reason: Service Unavailable

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Amila It is. Except the last line that says : [2018-05-21 23:37:08] Server     INFO  Started 2018/05/21 23:37:08 IST on port 3030

Comment: The localhost:3030 says HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--loc=` names a directory for a TDB1 database. The directory must exists; it can be empty or contain a prebuilt database.

`dataset.json.bz2` looks like a file.

If it contains RDF data, then use tdbloader to build the database first.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that as @AndyS mentioned, you have to have the Data directory. In Fuseki v3.12 (current version) this directory does not exist and you have to create it by yourself! I faced this problem since I was trying to start the server from a YouTube video which did not mention this!